# When is a group $G$ isomorphic to $(G/N) \times N$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ denote a group and $N$ denote a normal subgroup thereof. Then there's always a bijection $G \rightarrow (G/N) \times N$, owing to the fact that $G$ and $(G/N) \times N$ have the same cardinality. However, these groups usually aren't isomorphic. For example, if $G = \mathbb{Z}/4$ and $N = \mathbb{Z}/2$, then $(G/N) \times N$ is $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$, which is not isomorphc to $\mathbb{Z}/4.$

Sometimes however they're isomorphic. For example, if $G$ is a finitely-generated abelian group and $N$ is its subgroup of torsion elements, then a weak form of the structure theorem for finitely-generated abelian groups says that $G$ is isomorphic to $(G/N) \times N$.

> **Question.** For which normal subgroups $N$ is this true?

Comment: For abelian groups, this is exactly when there is a homomorphism $G\to N$ such that the composition $N\subseteq G\to N$ is the identity on $N$. Equivalently, there is a homomorphism $G/N\to G$ such that $G/N\to G\to G/N$ is the identity on $G/N$. For non-abelian groups, it's not so nice, since these conditions only imply that $G$ is the semidirect product of $N$ and $G/N$ (where $G/N$ is seen as a subgroup of $G$ by the aforementioned homomorphism $G/N\to G$).

Comment: It is hard to know what kind of answer you are expecting to such a general question.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension.

Comment: It is true for example if $G$ is nilpotent and finite and $N$ one of its Sylow subgroups.

Comment: A trivial answer to your question is that $N$ is. Direct factor of $G$. Is this what you wanted to know?

Comment: @Arthur, what's the map $G \rightarrow N$ you're referring to when $G$ is a f.g. abelian group and $N$ is its set of torsion elements?

Comment: @Goblin if you pick a (minimal) set of generators, it would be a map that sends every torsion free generator to $0$, and every torsion generator to itself.

Comment: @Arthur, I see. So in other words, it acts as the identity on torsion elements and sends torsion-free elements to $0$. Is that right?

Comment: @Arthur, actually I don't think the map I described is a group homomorphism in general. For instance, if $G$ is $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2$, and if $e_1 =(1,0)$ and $e_2 = (0,1)$, and if $f : G \rightarrow G$ is the map previously decribed, then $f(e_1+e_2) = 0$, but $f(e_1)+f(e_2) = 0+e_2 = e_2.$

Comment: That's because the map I described is not zero on non-torsion elements, it is _projection_ onto the torsion elements (as defined by how we choose our generators). In your case it would be $f(a,b)=(0,b)$.

Comment: @Arthur, how do we know such a map exists?

Comment: @goblin In that specific case? Because if the group is fg abelian, it is isomorphic to a product of different $\Bbb Z_n$ and some number of copies of $\Bbb Z$. By definition of product, we can project this goup onto its finite factors. And that's it.

Comment: @Arthur, to actually prove the correctness of the structure theorem for f.g. about groups it would be helpful to have the above factorization to use. Do you know how to describe this map without using the structure theorem.

Answer (score 3):

A trivial answer to your question that the normal subgroup $N$ splits off as a direct factor of $G$:
$$
G=N\times Q$$
for some subgroup $Q< G$. (I.e. there exists another normal subgroup $Q< G$ such that $Q\cap N=\{1\}$, $[N,Q]=\{1\}$ and $G=NQ$.) Whether you are looking for anything beyond this statement is unclear to me.

Edit. It is clear that if $G=G_1\times G_2$ then $G/G_1\cong G_2$, the isomorphism is given by the map $G_1\times g_2 \mapsto g_2$.

Comment: That sounds interesting. So I guess my question amounts to: under what circumstances can we choose $Q$ to be isomorphic to $G/N$? However, I'm more interested in how you know that this is true. Is it a standard result?

Comment: @goblin Always.

Answer (score 2):

As Arthur mention in a comment, whenever there is a group homomorphism $p:G\to N$ whose restriction to $N$ is the identity, then $G$ is isomorphic to $N\ltimes \ker(p)$, where the action of $N$ on $\ker(p)$ is given by conjugation in $G$. But if $N$ is assumed to be normal, then this action is actually trivial, and thus $G$ is actually isomorphic to $N\times\ker(p)$. Indeed, in that case, for every $n\in N$ and $k\in \ker(p)$ we have $nkn^{-1}k^{-1}\in N$, and thus $$nkn^{-1}k^{-1}=p(nkn^{-1}k^{-1})=nn^{-1}=1,$$
which means that $nkn^{-1}=k$.

So a possible answer to your question is that there is an isomorphism if and only if $N$ is a *retract* of $G$.